# Looking for an in-memory database with same SQL syntax as Oracle

Tags: oracle, ado.net, automated-tests, embedded-database

I'm looking for a in-memory database that can be used for automatic testing of legacy ADO.NET code against Oracle. So the in-memory database should have the same SQL syntax as Oracle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why? You can get Oracle for nothing (legally). Why not just use the real thing?

Comment: I don't think it will be fast enough for automatic tests. But it may be the road to take.

Comment: I'd think there are legal impediments to an Oracle-clone ... not to mention that some parts of Oracle SQL might be incompatible with an in-memory implementation.  (Should it just ignore storage directives, etc)

Comment: Give the fact Oracle is suing Google about source code, 3rd part PLSQL is highly unlikely.  PostgreSQL has a lot of similar functionality, but still diverges.  If you want embedded Oracle, you'd best look at their offerings: http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Embedded

Comment: Assuming you aren't doing volume testing (which seems a valid assumption as the results would be meaningless), if you have a small amount of test data and a lot of memory you may end up with most of it cached anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well [Oracle IMDB Cache](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/1121/doc/timesten.1121/e14261/toc.htm) is the ideal product. I think automated testing would require a license, but see what you can negotiate with your local Oracle sales rep.

But I'd start with a regular DB, NOARCHIVELOG mode. Perhaps with temp and logs on some form of ram disk since you've got no need of recovery.

Also talk to Oracle Support as there are some hidden parameters that can be set to improve speed at the expense of recoverability (ie not generate redo at the expense of not being able to handle instance recovery).

Comment: @Marcus did you have any luck with this or what did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

try Oracle [TimesTen](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/timesten/overview/index.html)  I haven't played with it myself but believe it has the same syntax as Oracle RDBMS.